# Vb.net, Instantiating a class

Tags: vb.net

I have problem with assigning values to a defined class members. Classes OutgoingInvoicesData and OutgoingInvoicesDataHeader are automatically created from XML and are reachable through InteliSense.
So, what do I missed here or what do I doing wrong and how can I instantiate a class and assign values to its members without getting an error in order to serialize and deserialize it's data?

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim oid As OutgoingInvoicesData = New OutgoingInvoicesData()
    oid.Header.SupplierID = 26742352147 'Here: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    oid.Header.InvoiceType = 1
End Sub
End Class

<System.SerializableAttribute()>
<System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="http://mypage/OutgoingInvoicesData/v3.2")> 
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:= "http://mypage/OutgoingInvoicesData/v3.2", IsNullable:=False)>
Partial Public Class OutgoingInvoicesData
Private headerField As OutgoingInvoicesDataHeader

Public Property Header As OutgoingInvoicesDataHeader
    Get
        Return Me.headerField
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As OutgoingInvoicesDataHeader)
        Me.headerField = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class

<System.SerializableAttribute()>
<System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="http://mypage/OutgoingInvoicesData/v3.2")>
Partial Public Class OutgoingInvoicesDataHeader
Private supplierIDField As ULong
Private invoiceTypeField As Byte

Public Property SupplierID As ULong
    Get
        Return Me.supplierIDField
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ULong)
        Me.supplierIDField = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property InvoiceType As Byte
    Get
        Return Me.invoiceTypeField
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Byte)
        Me.invoiceTypeField = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property 'Header' is Nothing when initializing your class, so you cannot assign a value to its 'SupplierID'.

Change

```
Private headerField As OutgoingInvoicesDataHeader
```

to

```
Private headerField As New OutgoingInvoicesDataHeader
```

Comment: That works, thank you. Is here any way that "paste xml as classes" do this that way automatically?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry.

Comment: But with adwancing I get another one situation such is: Private uBLExtensionsField As UBLExtensionsUBLExtension(), which is Array and dont accept keyword New like: Private uBLExtensionsField As New UBLExtensionsUBLExtension(). What to do here?

Comment: What to do here? Learn the basics! An array can also be constructed with new, but its size cannot be changed afterwards (although it may be redimensioned which internally copies the array elements). But you probably already get an array from the deserialization and only have to assign it (otherwise the syntax would be ```Private uBLExtensionsField(<mySize> - 1) As UBLExtensionsUBLExtension```).

Comment: Thanks Cristoph. What else I do then learn the basics? If I would know - I wouldn't ask! Yes I get an array from deserialization which may vary in sise depending on other document of same type. How to define if we don't know a size of array?